# Windows could not start the RabbitMQ Service on local Computer

Tags: erlang, rabbitmq, message-queue

I am trying to start RabbitMQ service on my local Windows laptop but I keep getting this error:

[image]

I first downloaded erlang (OTP 19.0 Windows 64-bit Binary File) from here: http://www.erlang.org/downloads. 
Then I downloaded RabbitMQ from here: https://www.rabbitmq.com/install-windows.html

Erlang seems to have installed correctly - I don't see any errors in the logs. RabbitMQ shows this message in the installation logs:

```
Installing RabbitMQ service...
The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.
The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.
The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.
C:\Program Files\erl8.0\erts-8.0\bin\erlsrv: Service RabbitMQ added to system.
Error spawning C:\Program Files\erl8.0\erts-8.0\bin\epmd -daemon (error 0)
Starting RabbitMQ service...
The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.
The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.
The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.
C:\Program Files\erl8.0\erts-8.0\bin\erlsrv: Failed to start service RabbitMQ.
Error: The process terminated unexpectedly.
```

I uninstalled both, restarted my laptop and reinstalled but still doesn't work.

I also added Firewall Rules but still no luck. The 2nd firewall rule is for allowing connection for these ports: 4369, 25672, 5672, 5671, 15672, 61613, 61614, 1883, 8883

[image]

Comment: Seems like you are trying to install RabbitMQ in a folder that does not exist.

Comment: Can you post the directory name when you are trying to install RMQ? does the folder contains spaces or other special characters?

Comment: @Gabriele By default dir name was "RabbitMQ Server" I uninstalled and reinstalled to "RabbitMQ" still the same issue. Thanks

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I think I had the same problem which lies in the error

> The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.

... and that maybe when erlang was installed it for some reason is sets the **HOMEDRIVE** to *u:* or something silly.

From the command line run:

```
SET HOMEDRIVE=C:
```

Then try to run your rabbitmq-service again. You may have to **stop, remove, install, start** it again.

```
rabbitmq-service stop
rabbitmq-service remove
rabbitmq-service install
rabbitmq-service start
```

and please make sure that you have copied the **.erlang.cookie** from **c:\Windows** to the root of your user folder ( **C:\Users\{user}\** )

Answer (score 3):

```
Open the command prompt and run the following commands one by one:

c:\>cd\  
c:\>cd Program Files  
c:\Program Files>cd RabbitMQ Server  
c:\Program Files\RabbitMQ Server>dir  
c:\Program Files\RabbitMQ Server>cd rabbitmq_server-3.8.1  
c:\Program Files\RabbitMQ Server\rabbitmq_server-3.8.1>dir  
c:\Program Files\RabbitMQ Server\rabbitmq_server-3.8.1>cd sbin  
c:\Program Files\RabbitMQ Server\rabbitmq_server-3.8.1\sbin>dir  
c:\Program Files\RabbitMQ Server\rabbitmq_server-3.8.1\sbin>SET HOMEDRIVE=C:

c:\Program Files\RabbitMQ Server\rabbitmq_server-3.8.1\sbin>rabbitmq-service enable

c:\Program Files\RabbitMQ Server\rabbitmq_server-3.8.1\sbin>rabbitmq-plugins enable rabbitmq_management
```

and please make sure that you have copied the .erlang.cookie from c:\Windows to the root of your user folder ( C:\Users{user}\ )

Comment: This will work for the RabbitMQ service start issue

Answer (score 1):

Pls use below command, this worked for me

```
rabbitmq-service remove

rabbitmq-service install

rabbitmq-service start
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

`rabbitmq-service install`

then

```
rabbitmq-service start
```

again

Answer (score 0):

see that

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Ericsson\Erlang\ErlSrv\1.1\RabbitMQ
Machine
value is poiting to the right Erlang version